# Adding more tables to sql at runtime for multi tenant app

Tags: reactjs, database, postgresql, multi-tenant, remix.run

I am building a multi-tenant application and each tenant has their own subdomain-and dynamic content is served based on the subdomain. The problem I'm facing is how to handle multi-tenant in the db backend. I could possibly store the data in one database and don't know how to structure PostgreSQL so its adaptable and flexible. I could also change the database where the data is retrieved(like user profiles and other data), but don't want to incur over the top charges on a per tenant basis. Does anyone know of a way to structure my database to be flexible as my tenants grow or another solution?